# Cursor issue for 2 overlapping elements in same div

Tags: css, sass

I have sign up text box, where input field has a button inside it. the look is good. But, I need a cursor on sign up button. But I see cursor for text edit. i tried using z-index. But did not work. Please help me fix this issue.

```
css code:
 .email_container input {
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    color: #dad8d3;
    width: 273px;
    height: 38px;
    opacity: 0.32;
    border-radius: 19px;
  }
  .email_container .sign_up {
    width: 37.2px;
    height: 37.2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 235px;
  }
```

Comment: Please add your HTML code or a pen/fiddle

Comment: <div className={css.email_container}>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Type your email here" ref="email" value={email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    <button href={props.link || '#'} disabled={!isEmail(email)} className={css.sign_up}>
    <img src="footer.png" alt="Sign up" onClick={this._onSubmit} />
   </div>

Answer (score 2):

Add `position:relative; z-index:1;` to your `.email_container .sign_up`.